# force HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: mod-rewrite, server, apache2.4

While ago I used Cloudflare and the I used to redirect all the trafic from HTTP to HTTPS, but now due to some issues we need to shift back to HTTP, and we are no longer using Cloudflare,
some of our user are still visiting the old HTTPS url and they are getting "This site can’t be reached" error
we are using Apache/2.4.18 and I have tried all the suggested fixes to force all HTTPS trafic to HTTP but nothing worked 
here is my VirtualHost setting

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin myemail@live.com
ServerName mysite.com
ServerAlias www.mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite.com
CustomLog /var/www/logs/site_Log.log combined
ErrorLog /var/www/error_logs/site_Erro.log
<Directory /var/www/html/mysite.com>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
```

and here is my htaccess setting

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

and yes mod_rewrite is enabled

Comment: There must be a virtual host listening at port 443 (with SSL enabled) for the rewrite-rule to work. Otherwise the requests you want to rewrite will not even be seen by the server...

Comment: You mean default-ssl.conf, here is the setting for default-ssl.conf <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
 <VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
  SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </FilesMatch>
  <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
  SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

Comment: Do you have a valid ssl certificate?  ssl certificate is required in order to redirect a domain from `https` to `http`  because ssl is the first thing that is checked on server when you type your domain with `https` scheme and this happens before `https` to `http` redirect is applied

Comment: I have installed SSL, but still no luck

Answer (score 1):

Ok. so this htaccess worked for me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on

RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```